# how can I return a string with a variable if they are received from the server in the following form

Tags: reactjs

from server i get:

```
const sx = <p>Hello {{username}}</>
```

in render:

```
const username = 'john';
return ( {sx} )
```

need see:

```
Hello john
```

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const sx = (username) => <p> Hello {username} </p>`

render: CALL THE FUNCTION..

```
return (
  <div>
    {sx(username)}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: yes, its works, but my question not full, my sorry. I not have pure html, i get from server data

Comment: and get description = <p>hello, {username}</p>      const sx = (username) => description not work((

Comment: can you make a demo for this? [try this one](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)

Comment: Thanks, mb i have solution. But i m use 2 libraries ))) twig.js and html-react-parser

Answer (score 0):

From server i take object:

```
let description = obj ? obj.get('content') : ''; // <p>Hello, {{username}}</p>
```

I'm use:

```
const username = 'roman';
const template = twig({
    data: description
});
const ssx = template.render({username: username});
return (
   <div>{Parser(ssx)}</div> )
```

result:
     Hello, roman